# undefined method 'gsub' for #

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I keep getting this error when running my script. I'm quite new to Ruby so pleaes excuse my arrogance.

I'm scripting with Nuix which has JRuby support built in.

This is my code;

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'socket'
require 'rubygems'
require 'java'

java_import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

    module JSwing
      include_package javax.swing
    end

    def dropdown()

        ar = Array.new

        $current_case.getRootItems().each do set
        ar  set.guid()
        end

        names2 = JSwingJOptionPane.showInputDialog(nil, Please enter the name of the item set to export to Relativity., 
                                                            Choose item set, -1, 
                                                            nil, ar.to_java(Object), ar[0])
        if (names2.nil)
        JSwingJOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nil, No Export Set Selected)
            abort()
            end
        return names2
    end

    def writeLine (filepath, line)
        File.open(filepath, 'a') { f1 f1.puts line }
    end 

    def writeLines(filepath, lines)

        #lines.each do output
        #   puts output
        #end

        File.open(filepath, 'w') { f2 
            lines.each do line
                f2.puts line
            end

        }
    end

        def writeLinesUTF(filepath, lines)
        #lines.each do output
        #   puts output
        #end
        #progress = NxProgressBar.new(Write to file, lines.size)
        #frame = progress.ui_setup
        #frame.setVisible(true)
        count = 0
        File.open(filepath, 'wUTF-16LE') { f2 
            f2.print uFEFF
            lines.each do line
            count += 1

            if count % 1000 == 0
                #progress.update_progress(count)
            end
                f2.puts line
            end
            #frame.dispose
        }
        end





    def checknull(value)

        return value.to_s.split.join(' ').encode('UTF-16LE') unless value.nil

    end

    def checknull!(value)

        rtn = value.to_s.split.join(' ').encode('UTF-16LE') unless value.nil
        #return value.to_s.split.join(' ') unless value.nil
    end

$workset = dropdown()
$item_set_name = $workset
$arr = []
$path = DBCP BenchmarkTestUTF16.csv
sql_date = DateTimeFormatforPattern('yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss.SSS')
#sqltest()
$sharedarray = []


a = $current_case.searchUnsorted(path-guid#{$workset})
puts a.count

protocol = jdbcjtdssqlserver
#manchester SQL - 10.65.148.25
db_url = protocol + 10.65.148.251433;databaseName=Tom-Dev;selectMethod=cursor;
connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(db_url,,)




Benchmark.bm do bench

bench.report(Build Queuet) {
    count = 0
    $queue2 = Queue.new

    a.each do item
        $queue2  item
        count += 1
        if count = 10000
            break
        end
    end
    }
    puts $queue2.size

    bench.report(checknull! itemt) {

    share = Mutex.new

    #progress = NxProgressBar.new(Progress, $queue2.size)
    #frame = progress.ui_setup
    #frame.setVisible(true)
    #sharedarray = []
    threads2 = []
    #count = 0

    16.times do
      threads2  Thread.new do
        # loop until there are no more things to do

        until $queue2.empty      
          item = $queue2.pop(true) rescue nil
            if item
                begin

                    share.synchronize {

                        sqlinsert = INSERT INTO dbo.SH_TEST (item_guid,item_top_level_guid, item_parent_guid, 
                                 item_md5, item_kind, item_type, item_title, 
                                 item_file_size, item_extension, item_language, 
                                 item_name, item_failure_message, item_Process_Batch, 
                                 item_Process_Export, item_from, item_to, item_cc, item_bcc, 
                                 item_email_subject, item_path, item_case, item_has_text, 
                                 item_has_native, item_NativePath, item_TextPath, 
                                 item_conversation_index, item_lotus_thread, 
                                 item_position) 
                                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                        statementLog = connection.prepareStatement(sqlinsert)
                        begin
                            items_processed = 0
                            begin
                                items_processed = items_processed + 1

                                statementLog.setString(1, checknull!(item.guid))
                                statementLog.setString(2, checknull!(item.getTopLevelItem().nil  ''  item.getTopLevelItem.getGuid()))
                                statementLog.setString(3, checknull!(item.getParent().nil  ''  item.getParent.getGuid()))
                                statementLog.setString(4, checknull!(item.getDigests().getMd5()))
                                statementLog.setString(5, checknull!(item.getKind().getName()))
                                statementLog.setString(6, checknull!(item.getType().getName()))
                                statementLog.setString(7, checknull!(item.getProperties['Title']))
                                statementLog.setString(8, checknull!(item.getFileSize().to_s))
                                statementLog.setString(9, checknull!(item.getCorrectedExtension()[0..10]))
                                statementLog.setString(10, checknull!(item.getLanguage()))
                                statementLog.setString(11, checknull!(item.getName()))
                                statementLog.setString(12, checknull!(item.getProperties[FailureDetail]))
                                statementLog.setString(13, checknull!($current_case.getName() + '_' + item.getBatchLoadDetails().getBatchId()))
                                statementLog.setString(14, checknull!($current_case.getName() + '_' + $item_set_name))
                                if item.getCommunication.nil 
                                    statementLog.setString(15, checknull!(item.getProperties['From']  item.getProperties['Mapi-Sender-Email-Address']))
                                    statementLog.setString(16, checknull!(item.getProperties['To']  item.getProperties['Mapi-Display-To']  item.getProperties['SendTo']))
                                    statementLog.setString(17, checknull!(item.getProperties['Cc']  item.getProperties['Mapi-Display-Cc']  item.getProperties['CopyTo']))
                                    statementLog.setString(18, checknull!(item.getProperties['Bcc']  item.getProperties['Mapi-Display-Bcc']  item.getProperties['BlindCopyTo']))
                                else
                                    statementLog.setString(15, checknull!(item.getCommunication.getFrom().nil  ''  item.getCommunication.getFrom().join(';')))
                                    statementLog.setString(16, checknull!(item.getCommunication.getTo().nil  ''  item.getCommunication.getTo().join(';')))
                                    statementLog.setString(17, checknull!(item.getCommunication.getCc().nil  ''  item.getCommunication.getCc().join(';')))
                                    statementLog.setString(18, checknull!(item.getCommunication.getBcc().nil  ''  item.getCommunication.getBcc().join(';')))
                                end                             

                                statementLog.setString(19, checknull!(item.getProperties['Subject']  item.getProperties['Mapi-Subject']  item.getProperties['Mapi-Display-Name']))
                                statementLog.setString(20, checknull!(item.getLocalisedPathNames().join('')))
                                statementLog.setString(21, checknull!($current_case.getName())  )
                                statementLog.setString(22, checknull!(item.getTextObject().isAvailable()  1  0))
                                statementLog.setString(23, checknull!(item.getBinary().isAvailable()  1  0))
                                statementLog.setString(24, item.getBinary().isStored() == false  ''  checknull!(item.getBinary().getStoredPath()))
                                statementLog.setString(25, item.getTextObject().isStored() == false  ''  checknull!('' + Socket.gethostname + '' + item.getTextObject().getStoredPath().to_s.gsub!('','$')))
                                statementLog.setString(26, checknull!(item.getProperties['Mapi-Conversation-Index']))
                                statementLog.setString(27, checknull!(item.getProperties['$TUA'].nil  ''  item.getProperties['$TUA'].gsub('{','').split(',').first)) #Experimental!! Lotus notes conversation threading)
                                statementLog.setString(28, checknull!(item.getPosition().toArray().map{v #{v}}.join(-))) #Experimental, can be used to make relational those items from the same folder.)

                                statementLog.execute_update

                                #progress
                                if items_processed % 1000 == 0
                                    print .
                                    stdout.flush
                                end
                            rescue Exception = e
                            puts #{e}
                            p e.backtrace
                            puts statementLog
                        end
                        ensure
                        statementLog.close
                        end

                    }
                rescue
                    #puts item.guid                 
                end
            end
        end
        # when there is no more work, the thread will stop

      end
    end
    # wait until all threads have completed processing

    threads2.each do t
        t.join
    end
    bench.report(Write Lines n){
        #writeLinesUTF($path, sharedarray)
    }
    #frame.dispose

}







#end
end

return
```

And this is the exception that keeps getting thrown;

```
undefined method `gsub' for #<#<Class:0x45716032>:0x13685969>
["<script>:194:in `(root)'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "<script>:142:in `(root)'"]
```

I believe it might be being thrown on the `checknull` function, however I cannot be certain.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this is too much code for us to go through.

Answer (score 9):

Before using 'gsub' on a string try using 'to_s' just before that to convert it to string if it isn't a string. Something like this:

```
something.to_s.gsub(...)
```